# Why std::string is standard layout type when release, but is not standard layout type when debug?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>
int main()
{
    std::cout << std::is_standard_layout<std::string>::value;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I use Visual Studio 2017 to compile the code. When in debug mode, it output 0. But when in release mode, it output 1. What make it happened?

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://godbolt.org/z/o7MW6Yzeb check and provide full list of compiler flags used when building in for debug mode.

Comment: My msvc version is v14.16

Comment: sadly godbolt doesn't reach this version.

Comment: Note also you are confusing toolset version with MSVC version. For VS 2017 it should be +19.10 .

Comment: Why do you care?  A class being standard-layout is useful only to code that accesses its member variables directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is a somewhat simplified explanation, because most of the classes described below are templated, and I'm omitting such details for brevity.

In MSVC 2017 toolset version 14.16, the `std::string` class is derived from `_String_alloc` class, which has a single private data member `_Mypair` of type `_Compressed_pair`. The class `_Compressed_pair` is derived from an empty `std::allocator<char>` class, and has a single private `_Myval2` data member of type `_String_val`. The class `_String_val` is derived from `_Container_base` class, plus it has three private data members: `_Bx` of a `union` type `_Bxty` (which is able to provide either an in-place buffer for small string optimizations or a pointer to the dynamically-allocated buffer for regular strings), `_Mysize` and `_Myres`, both of `size_type`, tracking the length and the reserved storage size for the string.

In **release** mode, when [`_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/iterator-debug-level) is `#define`d as `0`, the `_Container_base` is an alias for an empty `struct _Container_base0`. However, compiling in **debug** mode, when `_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL` is not `0`, the `_Container_base` is an alias for a non-empty `struct _Container_base12`, which contains a single public data member `_Myproxy` (which is a pointer to a `_Container_proxy` structure).

Now, here's the catch: one of the [requirements for the standard layout type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/StandardLayoutType) is that all of its (non-static) data members shall be declared in the same class (i.e., either all declared in the most derived class itself or all declared in some particular base class, but not scattered among different classes). Thus, because of the aforementioned `_Container_base12` helper structure (used for debugging purposes), `_String_val` does not satisfy this requirement any more, and therefore cannot be considered being a standard layout type. In particular, its `_Myproxy` data member is declared in `_Container_base12`, whereas `_Bx`, `_Mysize` and `_Myres` data members are declared directly in `_String_val` itself.

By implication, when using a non-zero `_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL`, the `std::string` class itself no longer satisfies the standard layout type requirements, since one of the rules is that all (non-static) data members and base classes shall themselves be standard layout types as well.

While this does answer your question about origins of the difference, please bear in mind that these are just undocumented, implementation-specific details, not to be relied upon. Microsoft may change/reorganize their library code in the future. For example, MSVC 2019 toolset version 14.28 already uses composition instead of inheritance: there, the `std::string` class is not derived from `_String_alloc` anymore, and instead directly contains its own single `_Mypair` data member of type `_Compressed_pair`. (Fortunately, [ABI compatibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017) between toolsets v14.28 and v14.16 is still preserved this way, it seems, because the resultant memory layout of `std::string` remains the same.) And of course the reasoning is similar for MSVC 2019 / toolset v14.28 regarding `std::string` not being standard layout in debug mode. However, some future version may bring breaking changes, and then at some point perhaps the `std::is_standard_layout<std::string>::value` observed in debug mode may even change to `true` without notice.