OpenCV won't read the image even though the path is correct, string appears empty (imread_(''): can't open/read file: check file path/integrity)
I'm trying to learn opencv in c++ as i will be required to use it very soon. The problem i'm facing is exactly as the title says: opencv won't open (cv::imread()) any image even though the path is correct.
When i use cv::imread(path) i get the error
[ WARN:0@1.387] global loadsave.cpp:241 cv::findDecoder imread_(''): can't open/read file: check file path/integrity
I have tried using /, //, \\\\ \\. I tried using the absolute path and the relative path. I also have tried opening different images in different folders and in differents disks as well (c:/ and d:/). I also have tried updating my opencv installation.
I'm now using OpenCV 4.10 and am using Visual Studio 2022.
This is the code i am trying to run:
#pragma once
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <windows.h>
#include <shobjidl.h>

int main() {

    cv::String filepath("D:/repos/faculdade/dataset/AnaCedran60dias.jpg");

    cv::Mat cvimg = cv::imread(filepath, 0);

    std::cout << "Path:\n" << filepath << std::endl;

    if(cvimg.empty())
        std::cout << "img wasnt read" << std::endl;
    
    cv::waitKey(0);
}


imread_('') clearly states that passed path is empty. Do you compile the code successfully?

Works perfectly fine for me on Linux: https://pastebin.com/auVh2BxR; Note that you can do backslashes for Windows filepaths in the string by using a \\ (escaped backslash).

try std::string instead of cv::String. -- never ever use magic numbers like 0 for a flag. IMREAD_GRAYSCALE is the identifier to use here.

this is once again that bug that causes non-empty strings to be seen as empty. I haven't seen conclusive fixes or explanations for the phenomenon so far. it doesn't happen to everyone, so it's not a fundamental issue with OpenCV or MSVC, but it only shows up on Windows with MSVC (so far). it's probably some issue of mismatched versions or misconfiguration or system settings messing with strings in some way.

@ChristophRackwitz I’ve never even heard of such a bug. I’m curious to know what you know about it now.

not much. several people have had this happen. literally some string that can't possibly be empty will "arrive" empty at the OpenCV API or somewhere in OpenCV. if I had to speculate (I think someone speculated before me) there might be some multibyte stuff going on that causes the string to contain a null byte right away. this is a recent issue, several months but less than a year of history.

#pragma once is normally placed in header files only.

Try std::cout << filepath << std::endl

In MSVC double check that you are using the same kind of MSVC runtime lib (debug/release/threaded/non-threaded) in your project and in opencv-build. If you are mixing the runtime libs you will get heap corruptions that often get visible as wrong string content. For example you might see strange symbols in the title of a cv::namedWindow title.

@abnt2008 I would very much like to hear your results from trying these suggestions.

Hey guys, I'm sorry for the late response. So the code do compile successfully and I can read the print "image wasnt read". I tried using std::string but the results are the same. And using IMREAD_GRAYSCALE also yield the same results. As for the escapes backslash, no success too. I am starting to think it might be this bug that @ChristophRackwitz mentioned. Is there anything else I can try or any possible solution to this? Thanks for your comments!

@Micka where do i find this config?

when you build your own program, do you build it with the "debug" profile or the "release" profile? that should be a selectable thing in VS somewhere in the toolbar, or if it's no longer there, probably somewhere in the project settings. if you haven't, try both profiles. the release profile should work better than the debug profile (or at all), because OpenCV is built as "release".

@abnt2008 how did you install opencv? When you compiled it yourself you can check in you build process whether you used /MT or /MD or one of the other possibilities. By default nearly all opencv builds should be /MT so check whether in your project also /MT is selected. On a Release build, very likely /MT runtime lib will be active.

Hey guys, so it turns out I was running my app in debug mode and when changing to release, it fixed my error. I don't understand why that is the case, and i'm sorry for not pointing out i was running in debug mode in the first place. TBH I didn't know it was in debug mode as it compiled and finished with no visible warning or sign of the debugger. I'm quite new to Visual Studio too. Thanks to you all for your comments, you really helped me. Thanks @ChristophRackwitz for all your help!

unless someone posts an answer with an explanation of this situation (@Micka?), you should post an answer stating what did the trick. I'm inclined to make this a "canonical". don't be worried if your question experiences some edits. that's to make it appear more "fitting" to people when they look for their own symptoms that fit the situation. -- all you C++ people, feel free to enrich with suitable tags.

Possible higher-level canonical (there has to be a better one, this is general enough problem): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73895291/why-cant-we-mix-debug-and-release-builds-with-msvc

Although it would be useful to have some generic OpenCV related canonical for this sort of problem too. Not sure how to title it, but it's bound to happen with anything taking an std::string. (So imread, imwrite at al. the VideoIO stuff, quite a few HighGUI functions, I guess loading of models, ...)

I really hope they (whoever they may be) train their LLMs on the entire page including comments. then there's a chance the model will remember this issue and regurgitate the findings.

So what solved my problem was changing the build profile to "Release". For some reason building it with the "Debug" profile caused the string to be seen as empty, even though it wasn't.

The problem happens when you use imread() from a release-mode library in debug mode.
In Debug, you need to use the lib with d:  opencv_world4100d.lib

... assuming OpenCV provide such debug builds. The existence of this problem says no, they don't. They do provide release builds, so that's the mode I would recommend in general.

@ChristophRackwitz  Have you installed OpenCV 4.10.0 and checked the folder opencv\build\x64\vc16\lib? OpenCV lib (https://github.com/opencv/opencv/releases/download/4.10.0/opencv-4.10.0-windows.exe)

I just looked, and I saw that there are those debug libraries included in the official OpenCV binary release. I hadn't checked previously. OP must have manually set the release library for their debug build. I guess this should also have worked if OP set the debug library for the debug build.

@ChristophRackwitz Yeah, debug binaries have been in the Windows package since at least 2.x days. What's interesting is that I recall there being some rudimentary mechanism in OpenCV to catch those mix-ups. Although that might have been for release builds linking with debug library, and this seems to have been the other way round.
